# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty }\frac{x^{3}\sin\left ( (1/2)\pi x \right )}{e^{2\pi \sqrt{x}}-1}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I got an answer below

> \begin{align*}
> \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{3}\sin\left ( \frac{1}{2}\pi x \right )}{e^{2\pi \sqrt{x}}-1}\mathrm{d}x&=\frac{17}{16}-\frac{8}{3\pi }-\frac{7}{\pi ^{2}}+\frac{35}{2\pi ^{3}}-\frac{105}{16\pi ^{4}} \\&\approx 0.00145669538148559\cdots \cdots 
> \end{align*}

which agree with mathematica.But I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Cool result though

Comment: Ramanujan studied such integrals to a great extent in his paper "Some Definite Integrals Connected with Gauss's Sums" (*Messenger of Mathematics, XLIV, 1915, pp. 75-85*). Here at the end of the paper he mentions that integrals of type $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m}\sin n\pi x}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}} - 1}\,dx, \,\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m}\cos n\pi x}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}} - 1}\,dx$$ where $m$ is positive integer and $n$ is positive rational number, can be evaluated and gives some examples like $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\cos((1/2)\pi x}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}} - 1}\,dx = \frac{13 - 4\pi}{8\pi^{2}}$$

Comment: Link to Ramanujan's paper mentioned in previous comment: http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram12.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From integrals and series 'S':

Using the techniques in Ramanujan's
 paper "Some definite Integrals connected to Gauss's sums", I arrived at
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(tx)\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi x^2}{2} \right)}{\tanh(\pi x)}\, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{t^2}{2\pi} \right)\coth(t)-\frac{1}{2\sinh(t)}$$

My guess is that this equation can be manipulated to get the desired result. By manipulations I mean substitutions, differentiation, taking limits etc.

Here's the link to the paper:[Some definite Integrals connected to Gauss's sums](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram12.pdf)

Comment: The formula is indeed correct. But a simple modification (delta) has to be made to obtain the final result.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I recently posted this 1st step to an answer. I thought that it was wrong, so I made it CW, but after further investigation, it actually was right. Here was that post, without CW

Consider the integral:

$$f(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos ax}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}}-1}\text{dx}$$

Therefore: $$I=f'''\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

We can shift our integral to sum form, due to that $\cos$ term there.

$$f(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \int_0^\infty \frac{(ax)^{2n}}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}}-1}\text{dx}$$

Substituting $x\to x^2,\text{dx}\to2\text{dx}$

$$=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^na^{2n}}{(2n)!} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{4n+1}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\text{dx}$$

According to W|A, that integral actually has a closed form! Don't ask me how it got that...

$$-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^na^{2n}}{(2n)!} (2\pi)^{-4n-2}\text{Li}_{4n+2}(1)\Gamma(4n+2)$$

This is only partial, but might help.

Comment: The substitution $x\to x^2$ forgets a factor $x$ (fortunately, or the $n=0$ integral would diverge as $x\to0$).

Comment: @Did Oh. I see. Good point.

Comment: The integral still does carry a closed form, with W|A again: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+inf+x%5E(4n%2B1)+%2F(e%5E(2+pi+x)-1)

Comment: Of course it does. Just correct your answer.

Comment: "Don't ask me how it got that..." The derivation is actually straightforward: expanding the fraction into powers of $e^{-x}$, one gets, for every positive $s$, $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx=\sum_{k\geqslant1}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-kx}dx=\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac1{k^s}\Gamma(s)=\zeta(s)\Gamma(s),$$ to be used for every $s=4n+2$, and the only remaining mysterious part might be why W|A prefers to write $\zeta(s)$ as $\mathrm{Li}_s(1)$...

Comment: A more serious concern about the formula proposed in this answer for $f(a)$ as a series is that the series actually diverges for every $a\ne0$. To wit, $\zeta(4n+2)=\mathrm{Li}_{4n+2}(1)\to1$ and $u^n\Gamma(4n+2)/(2n)!\to\infty$ for every nonzero $u$, hence the $n$th term of the series goes to infinity.